# Workbench Mismatch Version Mysql 8 to 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have installed the latest version of Workbench but i need to download a db mysql in 5.6

I look around and follow other question but no one resolve problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/crTz3.jpg

Workbench and Mysql 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download archived versions from [here](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/). Or if you have the MySQL server installed, you can find mysqldump.exe in the bin folder.

Comment: Thank you so much!